# Meaning of 意識してる in this sentence

Tags: meaning, words

Does 意識してる have a different meaning than "being aware" in the following sentence?

> この漫画の原作を書く時は自分の中にある１番悪い部分をどれだけ出せるか…ってことを意識してます。

Considering that the sentence that comes before is a question, it comes natural to me to translate 意識してる as "I wonder", but I couldn't find this meaning in dictionaries. Is my interpretation correct? Or I got it completely wrong? Thank you for your help!

EDIT: my translation attempt.

> I wonder(?) to what extent I am able to convey the worst part that's inside me when I write the story of this manga.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think 意識してる in your sentence means "pay attention" "keep in mind" (close to 気にしている, 注意を払っている or 心にとめている).

So I think it can translate to something like:

"I (always) pay attention to how much I am able to convey the most evil part that's inside me when I write the story of this manga."

by which the author practically means:

"I always try as much as I can to convey the most evil part that's inside me when I write the story of this manga."

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, in this case, the meaning of 意識 is more close to "think" or "pay attention", rather than "being conscious, aware", right?

Comment: @Marco Precisely! "being conscious/aware"(≂気づいている)ではなく、"(actively) think/pay attention"(≂(積極的に)考える・注意を払う)という感じだと思います。

Comment: how about 不思議 ? I found that the meaning is "wonder" too, am I wrong?

Comment: @Marco "being concious / aware of " is more likely to be 意識がある rather than 意識する.